# How do I stop this NSThread?

Tags: ios, swift, background-process, nsthread

I've got a function that gets called when my app enters background mode.  I''d like to stop the thread if user re-opens the app.  Nothing I'm trying works so far though.

Here's my code so far:

```
class Neversleep {
    private static var callback : (()->Void)?
    private static var thread: NSThread?

    static func start(callback: ()->Void) {
        self.callback = callback

        Neversleep.thread = NSThread(target: self, selector: #selector(Neversleep.task), object: nil)
        Neversleep.thread?.start()

    }

    static func stop() {
        print("NEVERSLEEP:STOP")
        Neversleep.thread?.cancel()

    }

    @objc static func task() {

        while (true)
        {
            sleep(3);
            print("we are still running!")
            callback?()
        }
    }
}
```

I call Neversleep.start() from app Delegate's DidEnterBackground method.

I'm calling Neversleep.stop() from willEnterForeground...but it's not stopping the thread.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here.  But what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `cancel` on a thread doesn't automatically kill the thread. The actual body of the thread needs to stop whatever it is doing when its thread is cancelled.

Update your `task` function like this:

```
@objc static func task() {
    while (!NSThread.currentThread.cancelled)
    {
        sleep(3);
        print("we are still running!")
        callback?()
    }
}
```

Double check the actual method and property names for `currentThread` and `cancelled`. I'm not 100% sure what they are named in Swift 2.

Even with the above, you will likely get one more call to `callback` after the thread is cancelled due to the `sleep`. You can fix this with:

```
@objc static func task() {
    while (!NSThread.currentThread.cancelled)
    {
        sleep(3);
        print("we are still running!")
        if (!NSThread.currentThread.cancelled) {
            callback?()
        }
    }
}
```